# erase part of a URL using htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla, virtuemart

i need to remove part of Joomla/Virtuemart generated SEF URI using .htaccess
the URI represents a menu hierarchy and structured this way:

online-store
         - inner-store
              -product-catalog

this is the resulting URI:

```
www.domain.com/online-store/inner-store/product-catalog
```

i would like to change it to:

```
www.domain.com/online-store/product-catalog
```

thought this might help but its not making any difference

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteRule ^online-store/inner-store/\d+-(.+) /online-store/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i know its not considered good practice but i can't change the menu structure.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex `\d+-(.+)` will match 1 or more digits followed by hyphen followed 1 or more any thing

Try this code instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(online-store)/inner-store/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure this is first rule in your `.htaccess` and use a different browser to test it to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, seems to work but now everything under /online-store is redirected to  /index.php?option=com_virtuemart. i guess virtuemart router needs to be dealt with

Comment: This above rule will just redirect `/online-store/inner-store/product-catalog` to `/online-store/product-catalog` after that virtuemart router needs to be dealt. As I suggested Just make sure above rule is first rule in your .htaccess before regular virtuemart router rule.